# "My name is X and I come from Syria" vs. "My name is X and I am from Syria"

Tags: expression-choice

I am trying to edit English subtitles for a short video on an educational project. A person there says something (in Swedish) which the Swedish copywriter translated as

> My name is Hamdi and I come from Syria.

For me this feels slightly odd; I am suspicious that this is just a word-by-word translation from Swedish; hence I am inclinded to correct it to

> My name is Hamdi, and I am from Syria.

but then I am not a native speaker of English myself (German background), so I am not sure about it.

Clearly subtitles in a video documentary have to be as short, simple, unambiguous and accessible as possible, or in other words: the sentence should be as straightforward as they come.

So, which one is better?

(Note that this question is not about grammar. Both sentence are acceptable in terms of grammar. It is about stylistic appropriateness for the purpose.)

Comment: The person who voted for "close" is invited to explain his or her reason. Thank you. - There is a tag "expression-choice" available, and it is explicitely for questions about selecting the best possible expression from a given set. So what could be wrong with my question?

Comment: It's not actually a "close" vote. I voted to migrate the question to [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), on the grounds that this isn't something that would concern the target user base here *(linguists, etymologists, and (serious) English language enthusiasts)*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Thanks for the explanation. I might add, however, that I asked this question not as an English language learner but as a "serious English language enthusiast", and here especially with the aim of delivering a professional subtitling. Hope that counts?

Comment: Both are perfectly correct of course, but my personal preference is 'my name is Hamdi and I'm from Syria'. In Arabic it would be 'ana min Syria' which in a word-for-word translation is 'I from Syria' since Arabic doesn't use the copula in this context.

Comment: ChristianGeiselmann: Well, I'm certainly not going to stick my neck out and claim you're *not* a "serious English language enthusiast". But hopefully *you* aren't going to complain that "English Language **Learners**" implies negative characterization. There are few if any contexts where native Anglophones would distinguish between *[person] **is / comes** from [place]*. And *approximately*, I'd say if *native speakers* would find the question trivial or "meaningless", it doesn't belong on ELU.

Comment: Heh heh. Short bit from the movie "Short Circuit." Speaking to a guy with dark skin, straight black hair, dark brown eyes, and a very pronounced accent. "Where are you from?"  "Chicago." "No, I mean your family." "Ahhh! New Jersey!"

Comment: You are on the wrong site. Try SE English Language Learners

Comment: @FumbleFingers  I do indeed not see anything negative about being an English language *learner*. I even would point out that every working brain is always a learning brain  whatever it does. So, of course, also linguists (which I may say I am sort of), etymologists (which I am at least on an occasional base) and serious enthusiasts (which I am anyway) are always learners as well, nolens volens. Hence I even struggle to understand the differentiation of the two groups, unless you understand "learners" as "total beginners". And my question was not intended for a public of such. Cheers.

Comment: ChristianGeiselmann: There were mixed reactions to the idea of a separate "Learners" site when it was set up some years ago, and very likely not all ELU users today endorse the existence of ELL. But *in practice*, although obviously ELL handles many "basic" questions from "total beginners", it also gets quite a few from people you'd be unlikely to recognize as non-native speakers just from the actual text in their posts. And because the *Answers* are more targeted to nns (often, taking special account of the asker's specific *native* language), I think they tend to get better "service" there!

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Thanks for the explanation. I appreciate your attention, and I understand the idea behind it; although I would not have been supportive of the split had I been participant to that debate, for reasons outlined above; moreover, there are anyway so many questions here in ELU that, following the ELU-ELL-devide logic, would rather fit into ELL that I am all the more unconvinced of the concept. See for example the most recent https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/517237/what-does-fancy-being-mean, which his a simple request for the meaning of a word to be explained.

Comment: ChristianGeiselmann: I don't know if you've ever struggled (or might *still* struggle) with how English uses ***will*** for "future" referents. But I certainly think [this ELL answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/124176/126), for example, is useful to learners who are apt to say things like *We will eat **when you will sit down**.* More so than anything in the much longer answers to [*When I am 18, I will… or When I will be 18, I will…*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/105457/) or [*Future tense in conditional clauses*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56876/) on ELU.

Comment: @FumbleFingers   Your last comment refers to what exactly?

Comment: I mean non-native speakers often struggle with details of "idiomacy" in English. Specifically, that vexed issue about "future tense in conditional clauses" often leads nns to say things like *We will eat **when you will sit down***, which the natives would *never* say. I just happened to notice that ELL answer for other reasons, and it seemed to me it's a good example of a case where that "short & to the point" ***ELL*** answer would probably be more useful to the *average* learner than anything on either of the two ELU posts. YMMD, of course.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Ah, okay, now I understand. You wanted to give an example for a question that rightfully has its place in the ELL forum as opposed to the ELU forum. Yes, good example. - Still I think my question was not of that kind. Especially as native speakers (those who managed to answer before the question got closed) seem to be devided pretty much 50:50 over it. - I don't know, perhaps we have been talking past each other here. My question was not about grammar (both sentences are acceptable) but about stylistic appropriateness for the purpose.

Comment: At least one of the answerers here isn't a native speaker anyway. But check out [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=He+comes+from+England%2CHe+is+from+England%2CHe%27s+from+England&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CHe%20comes%20from%20England%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CHe%20is%20from%20England%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CHe%20%27s%20from%20England%3B%2Cc0) showing how ***is from*** has displaced ***comes from***. I wouldn't say the latter is "formal" though - it's just that people tend to think that about "declining" usages.

Comment: ...and I would just add that the average *Englishman*, for example, probably wouldn't use *either* of your alternatives. He'd most likely say *My name's John Smith and I'm **English***.*

Answer (score 2):

"I come from Syria" sounds a bit formal, or bookish.

"Name's Hamdi. I'm from Syria." is just fine, and is shorter.

Comment: "I come from Syria" is perfectly idiomatic.

Comment: Well, that's interesting. So far it seems we have more or less a split vote for "I am from Syria" and "I come frome Syria" being the more appropriate solution. Okay. I learned something: my initial assumption that "I come from Syria" is pretty much unacceptable was wrong. Unfortunately I am not wiser at all now, as I got stuck in a 50:50 deadlock. Hm...

Comment: @christian Geiselmann.  I  do  not  know why  you  got  stuck.You  can  use  either of  the  two.The  preffered  form  is  I  come  from  Syria.

Comment: @KateBunting: I didn't say it wasn't.

Comment: I meant that I considered  it a natural, informal way of telling someone your country of origin.

Comment: @KateBunting: Try using it in a paragraph and see just how informal it sounds.

Comment: You may think it sounds formal - I disagree.

Answer (score 1):

> I am from  Syria.
>
> I  come  from  Syria.

I think both  are  correct  and  mean the  same thing.Both  mean  that  they  belong to  Syria. I think  native  speakers   of  English may  prefer  to  say   *I come from England* to  *I am from England*

Here  are  two links which  give  the usage.

https://www.spanishdict.com/translate/i%20am%20from%20india

https://www.linguee.com/english-german/translation/i+come+from+england.html

Comment: "...belong to Syria" sounds very wrong! The phrases indicate the origin and nothing more!

Comment: Thanks for the links. As for the Linguee finds: I think we need to be cautious here. The majority of these quotations with *come from England* have a pretty different context: not a person saying *I come *[or *am*] *from England* but things like *The calibre designation for shotguns comes from England*, or *Coming from England, I sailed to France* or whatever. I am not interested in the general frequency of the two terms. My question is regarding that specific context of a person stating their country of origin, in the briefest and most idiomatic way possible (i.e. for a video subtitle).