# What does "fancy being" mean?

Tags: meaning

I think I know what the verb 'fancy' means (feel a desire or liking for). But does 'fancy being' here have a different meaning?

> One needs to be audacious to proceed where no-one has gone before – and trail-blazers are often castigated for their effrontery. **Fancy being** ridiculed or ostracized for ascertaining the facticity of something ... for establishing a fact. ([ref](http://actualfreedom.com.au/library/topics/fact.htm))

Comment: Idiomatically, "fancy" as a verb can mean "imagine or suppose," as here: "Imagine [yourself] being ridiculed or ostracized..."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Sven mentioned, the verb *fancy* here means to **imagine**. It doesn’t here mean the secondary sense to **like** as it sometimes can (nor even the rather less common tertiary sense of to **breed**, as in pigeon fanciers or orchid fanciers).

The [paywalled OED entry](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/68026) gives these relevant subsenses:

> **I.** With reference to mental conception.
>
> 1. *trans*.
>
>    - 1a. To frame in fancy; to portray in the mind; to picture to oneself; to conceive, imagine. Also (with notion of fancy n. 3), to suppose oneself to perceive.
>
>    [*subsenses 1b, 1c, and 1d omitted*]
>
>    - 1e. In *colloq*. use often in the imperative as an exclamation of suprise. Also *absol*.

So this is an example of sense 1e; it’s being used as imperative exclamation of surprise much as if had been written:

> > Why, just imagine being ridiculed!

Comment: Well fancy that, I just upvoted this answer!

Comment: I'm not so sure; it seems at least equally possible (given the style of writing) that this is the 'Imagine yourself in the [challenging] situation where ...' sense.